# IResourceChangeEvent - how to identify a project delete/rename

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

How can I properly distinguish, inside an `IResourceChangeListener` that is added via `ResourcePlugin.getWorkspace().addResourceChangeListener(...)` that a Project was deleted / renamed?

Through trying things out, it would seem that the `IResourceChangeEvent.getDelta() -> IResourceDelta` would be the answer.

From [Eclipse API](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIResourceChangeEvent.html):

> After-the-fact batch reports of arbitrary creations, deletions and
>   modifications to one or more resources expressed as a hierarchical
>   resource delta. Event type is POST_CHANGE, and getDelta returns the
>   hierarchical delta. The resource delta is rooted at the workspace
>   root. These events are broadcast to interested parties after a set of
>   resource changes and happen whether or not autobuilding is enabled.
>   The workspace is closed for change during notification of these
>   events. The delta reported in this event cycle is identical across all
>   listeners registered for this type of event.

EDIT: adding my findings so far

So, the `Event.getType()` is `POST_CHANGE` and there needs to be either

- a delta that contains a child `IResourceDelta` that has the `getKind() == REMOVED` for a deletion, and the delta `getResource().getType() == PROJECT`  so that we know it's a project
  ( this `IResourceDelta` should not have any children )
- a `getDelta()` that contains two children `IResourceDelta` that have `getKind() == REMOVED` and `getKind() == ADDED`, also the `getResource().getType() == PROJECT`, and those `IResourceDelta` contain no children Deltas (I've observed that when a file is renamed/deleted, the `IProject` the resource belongs to is the one that is on the first row of children of the parent `Delta`...)

Can someone confirm this supposition? Is if it really necessary to do a tree depth search for children to realize if the Event is of a project rename/delete or a file/folder?

Answer (score 1):

- You need to add a resource change listener via
  `ResourcePlugin.getWorkspace().addResourceChangeListener(listener,
     IResourceChangeEvent.POST_CHANGE)`
- In your listener, use a `IResourceDeltaVisitor` to visit all the changes in the delta via
  `event.getDelta().accept(...)`
- The visitor should look into the projects that are `REMOVED`
- If you are expecting the project to be
  removed and created with the same name (as happens to files & folders
  during build events), then in addition to the `REMOVED`, also look for
  `REPLACED` in the delta

Comment: using this method, how would I recognize a project rename?

Comment: I have the same question as Vlad. How to identify rename event only ?

Comment: found an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170492/how-to-use-an-iresourcechangelistener-to-detect-a-file-rename-and-set-the-editor?lq=1

Comment: This is not answering the key point of the question, which I think is "how to distinguish between 'delete' versus 'rename' events".