# How to use an IResourceChangeListener to detect a file rename and set the EditorPart name dynamically?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

`IResourceChangeListener` listens to changes in project workspace for example if the editor part file name has changed.

I want to know how to access that particular `EditorPart` and change its title name accordingly (e.g. with `.setPartName`), or maybe the refresh the editor so that it shows the new name automatically.

Ideal would be if the `IResourceChangeListener`  has a *Rename* event type but does not seem to be the [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233155/iresourcechangeevent-how-to-identify-a-project-delete-rename).

Reference [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167290/rename-resource-file-does-not-change-editor-part-title).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IResourceChangeListener` does fire for rename/move events using a combination of the `REMOVED` kind and a `MOVED_TO` flag). You can test for that in the `IResourceDelta` with

```java
@Override
public void resourceChanged(final IResourceChangeEvent event)
{
  IResourceDelta delta = event.getDelta();

  // Look for change to our file

  delta = delta.findMember(IPath of file being edited);
  if (delta == null)
    return;

  if delta.getKind() == IResourceDelta.REMOVED
   {
     if ((delta.getFlags() & IResourceDelta.MOVED_TO) != 0)
      {
        IPath newPath = delta.getMovedToPath();

        ... handle new path
      }
   }
}
```

The code to handle the new path might be something like:

```java
IFile file = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(newPath);
if (file != null)
 {
   setInput(new FileEditorInput(file));

   setPartName(newPath.lastSegment());

   ... anything else required 
 }
```

Comment: How do I access the `setInput` and `setPartName` commands of the editor part from the other listener class that implements the `IResourceChangeListener` ?

Comment: You have to create the listener in the EditorPart and pass it a reference to the part. You can then call a method you write to handle the new path.

Comment: This should work. I want to know if this is a standard practice for renaming files. How does eclipse do the renaming? Since I want to my ide to follow similar conventions to eclipse.

Comment: Interestingly, I noticed that in case of renaming files such as a text file, the rename resource works ok. But the for the case for renaming the editor, the rename resource does not work.

Comment: What I have shown is basically what Eclipse editors do. For text editors there is more work to be done since things like document providers have to be updated.

Comment: Since the rename of text editors can already be done, why was the rename of the editors not already implemented but have to be done with the listener in my plugin ? Btw if possible could you point be to the source code for eclipse rename function so that I can take a look.

Comment: Non-text editors tend to be very varied, for example the plugin.xml editor also edits the manifest.mf and the build.properties so it needs more complex handling. The core of the text editor rename handler is `org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.FileDocumentProvider$FileSynchronizer` but all sorts of listeners are involved.

Comment: Is this a situation where `setInputWithNotify` is appropriate?

Comment: @Lii `setInput` just calls `setInputWithNotify` so do the same thing.

Comment: @greg-449 Hm. I think you've got it backwards. It is `setInputWithNotify` that calls `setInput`, not the other way around. According to the [docs on `setInput`](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fpart%2FEditorPart.html&anchor=setInput-org.eclipse.ui.IEditorInput-), when you call that method you should ensure to trigger a `PROP_INPUT` event afterwards. I think you should in your code either manually do that, or use `setInputWithNotify` instead.

Comment: @Lii For a plain `EditorPart` `setInputWithNotify` does set the input and does a notify - it does not actually call the `setInput` method. Confusingly for text editors `AbstractTextEditor` overrides this behavior and has `setInput` call `setInputWithNotify`.